# Android SQLite Passing Item selected in gridview into another Activity for editing

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent, gridview, android-gridview

Basically I have a Database with Accounts in them. I use `GridView` for viewing them, and from there you can select an `Account` and it will direct you to my Activity `AccountManagement` wherein you can modify, delete or just view all of the details of the selected `Account` from the `GridView`.

My problem is passing the data from the selection in `GridView` to `AccountManagement`.I'm not entirely sure how to use Intents for this properly. So far the code below doesn't work because I don't know how to pass the data into my `AccountManagement` and reference it properly from there.

Code is here, anything with `Acc` is problematic since `Acc` is where I'm supposed to put the data from `GridView`. I marked all those lines with a long `------` to make it easier to spot. Feel free to ask for any missing code.

EDIT DOWN BELOW WITH FINAL CODE FOR REFERENCE.

`AccountManagement` snippet:

```
public class AccountDetails extends Activity {

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
static public LinearLayout Linlay;
EditText txtName;
EditText txtAmt;
EditText txtPurpose;
TextView txtDate;
TextView txtEditDate;
Spinner spinStat;
Spinner spinTerm;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accdetails);

    Linlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linlay);
    spinStat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinStat);
    spinTerm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinTerm);
    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelName);
    txtAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelAmt);
    txtPurpose = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelPurpose);
    spinTerm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinTerm);
    txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colDate);
    txtEditDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colEditDate);
    spinStat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinStat);


    Utilities.ManageTermSpinner(AccountDetails.this, spinTerm);
    for(int i=0;i<spinTerm.getCount();i++)
    {
        long id=spinTerm.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
        if(id==Acc.getTerms())--------------------------------------------
        {
            spinTerm.setSelection(i, true);
            break;
        }
    }

    Utilities.ManageStatSpinner(AccountDetails.this, spinStat);
    for(int j=0;j<spinStat.getCount();j++)
    {
        long id=spinStat.getItemIdAtPosition(j);
        if(id==Acc.getStatus())--------------------------------------------
        {
            spinStat.setSelection(j, true);
            break;
        }
    }


    txtName.setText(Acc.getName());---------------------------------------
    txtAmt.setText(String.valueOf(Acc.getAmt()));-------------------------
    txtPurpose.setText(Acc.getPurpose());---------------------------------



    Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog diag = Alerts.DeleteConfirm(AccountDetails.this, Acc );--------------------------------
            diag.show();
        }
    });
}
```

`GridView` snippet:

This is where I should be getting the data to put into `Acc`  but I'm not sure how, so everything here can be changed since I'm not sure if this is the ideal way to do it.

```
        try {
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                                                long id) {
                try {



                    SQLiteCursor cr = (SQLiteCursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colName));
                    int amount = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colAmount));
                    String purpose = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colPurpose));
                    String Terms = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colTermsClass));
                    String Status = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colStatClass));
                    String date = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colDate));
                    String editdate = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colEditDate));
                    Account acc = new Account(name, amount, purpose, db.GetTermsID(Terms),date,editdate,db.GetStatID(Status));
                    acc.SetID((int) id);

                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AccountManager.this, AccountDetails.class);
                    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                    myIntent.putExtras(extras);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                           Alerts.CatchError(AccountManager.this, ex.toString());
                    }
                }


        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

EDIT:

`GridView` final snippet:

```
        try {
        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                                                                long id) {
                try {



                    SQLiteCursor cr = (SQLiteCursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colName));
                    int amount = cr.getInt(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colAmount));
                    String purpose = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colPurpose));
                    String Terms = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colTermsClass));
                    String Status = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colStatClass));
                    String date = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colDate));
                    String editdate = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.colEditDate));
                    Account acc = new Account(name, amount, purpose, db.GetTermsID(Terms),date,editdate,db.GetStatID(Status));
                    acc.SetID((int) id);


                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(AccountManager.this, AccountDetails.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("AccountObject", acc);
                    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                           Alerts.CatchError(AccountManager.this, ex.toString());
                    }
                }


        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
```

`AccountManagement` final snippet:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    final Account Acc = (Account) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("AccountObject");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accdetails);

    Linlay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.Linlay);
    spinStat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinStat);
    spinTerm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinTerm);
    txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelName);
    txtAmt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelAmt);
    txtPurpose = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDelPurpose);
    spinTerm = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinTerm);
    txtDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colDate);
    txtEditDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colEditDate);
    spinStat = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinStat);


    Utilities.ManageTermSpinner(AccountDetails.this, spinTerm);
    for(int i=0;i<spinTerm.getCount();i++)
    {
        long id=spinTerm.getItemIdAtPosition(i);
        if(id==Acc.getTerms())
        {
            spinTerm.setSelection(i, true);
            break;
        }
    }

    Utilities.ManageStatSpinner(AccountDetails.this, spinStat);
    for(int j=0;j<spinStat.getCount();j++)
    {
        long id=spinStat.getItemIdAtPosition(j);
        if(id==Acc.getStatus())
        {
            spinStat.setSelection(j, true);
            break;
        }
    }


    txtName.setText(Acc.getName());
    txtAmt.setText(String.valueOf(Acc.getAmt()));
    txtPurpose.setText(Acc.getPurpose());



    Button delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.delete);
    delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog diag = Alerts.DeleteConfirm(AccountDetails.this, Acc );
            diag.show();
        }
    });

    Button modify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.modify);
    modify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           AlertDialog diag = Alerts.ShowEditDialog(AccountDetails.this, Acc);
           diag.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't putting that 'acc' object into the Bundle and there by you are starting AccountDetails activity with empty Intent.

Here is an example: [Send object from one activity to another Activity using Intent](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-send-object-from-one-activity-to-another-activity/)

Comment: That would be kind of the question, I don't know how to do it. If I try putting `acc` into `Bundle extras = new Bundle(acc);` like so it gives me a `Cannot resolve constructor`

Comment: @Astatine0936 check updated answer. Refer the example given into the link!

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it and get back to you.

Comment: Got it to work now, thank you very much. I'll post the final code I ended up with in an EDIT for future references. Cheers!